# Flux of a vector field through a sphere

Tags: vector-fields

What is the flux of the vector field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(x- y^2z, ysinz, cosz)$ through the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$?

*What I have done:*

$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{f}= 1+ sinz -sinz= 1 $

I know that the flux is $\iiint\limits_{V}\nabla\cdot \mathbf{f} dxdydz= \iiint\limits_{V}1 dxdydz $. But I don't know what limits to use.

Comment: You don't need limits: the last triple integral you got it's the sphere's volume...

Comment: The last triple integral represents exactly the volume of your sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\iint_S \vec{f}\cdot \vec{ds}=$$
$$\iiint_V \nabla\cdot \vec{f} dv=$$
$$\iiint_Vdxdydz=$$
volume of the sphere
$$=\frac 43 \pi (\;radius\;)^3$$

but, the equation of your sphere is
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=4=R^2$$

Comment: so the answer is $\frac{32\pi}{3}$ ?

Comment: @PadChipper Yes exact {}{}{}{}{}